# Athena/Presto : complex structure/array

Tags: sql, json, presto, amazon-athena, unnest

Think that I am asking the impossible here, but throwing it out there.
Trying to query some json in Athena.
The data I'm working with looks like this (excerpt)

```
condition={
        "foranyvalue:stringlike":{"s3:prefix":["lala","hehe"]},
        "forallvalues:stringlike":{"s3:prefix":["apples","bananas"]
}
```

.. and I need to get to here :
[image]

... PLUS:the key names are not fixed, so one day I might get:

```
condition={"something not seen before":{"surprise":["haha","hoho"]}}
```

With that last point, I was hoping to treat this an an array, and start by splitting the 'foranyvalue' and 'forallvalues' parts into separate rows.
but with everything wrapped in {}, it refuses to unnest.

But despite the above failed plan - ANY tips on solving this by ANY means gratefully received !

Thank You

Comment: Is `condition` a name of a column? Is the JSON always in form `{ "some_key:with_colon": {"some_key": ["array", "of", values"]}, "some_other_key:with_colon" ....}`? Does the inner `{...}` always have exactly 1 entry?

Comment: Piotr (1)Condition is the name of a column.
(2)"some_key_with_OR_WITHOUT_colon"
(3)inner {} always 1 entry  -  thanks

Comment: .. sorry, the 'array of values' could also just be a plain single string (with no square [] brackets)

Answer (score 2):

When you have JSON data that does not have a schema that is easy to describe you can use `STRING` as the type of the column and then use Athena/Presto's [JSON functions](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/json.html) to query them, in combination with casting to `MAP` and `UNNEST` to flatten the structures.

One way of achieving what I think you're trying to do would be something like this:

```
WITH the_table AS (
  SELECT CAST(condition AS MAP(VARCHAR, JSON)) AS condition
  FROM (
    VALUES
    (JSON '{"foranyvalue:stringlike":{"s3:prefix":["lala","hehe"]},"forallvalues:stringlike":{"s3:prefix":["apples","bananas"]}}'),
    (JSON '{"something not seen before":{"surprise":["haha","hoho"]}}')
  ) AS t (condition)
),
first_flattening AS (
  SELECT 
    SPLIT(first_level_key, ':', 2) AS first_level_key,
    CAST(first_level_value AS MAP(VARCHAR, JSON)) AS first_level_value
  FROM the_table
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST (condition) AS t (first_level_key, first_level_value)
),
second_flattening AS (
  SELECT
    first_level_key,
    second_level_key,
    second_level_value
  FROM first_flattening
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST (first_level_value) AS t (second_level_key, second_level_value)
)
SELECT
 first_level_key[1] AS "for",
 TRY(first_level_key[2]) AS condition,
 second_level_key AS "left",
 second_level_value AS "right"
FROM second_flattening
```

I've included the two examples you gave as an inline `VALUES` list in the first CTE, and exactly what to do in the table declaration (i.e. what type for the column to use) and what processing to do in the query (i.e. the cast) depends on your data and how you want/can set up the table. YMMV.

The query flattens the JSON structure in a couple of separate steps, first flattening the first level of keys and values, then the keys and values of the inner documents. It might be possible to do this in one step, but doing it in two at least makes it easier to read.

Since the first level keys don't always have the colon I've used `TRY` to make sure that accessing the second value doesn't break anything. You could perhaps filter out values without a colon earlier and avoid this, since you're not interested in them.

Comment: Your answer has saved my days. Many thanks .
Can you please help to ready following JSON data

[{"a":"12","b":"gps"},{"a":"40","b":"stat"},{"a":"79","b":"third party"}]